# Equation to oxygen diffusion on the sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I am reading the book *The Mathematics of Diffusion* by J. Crank (cf. [Crank_1975_Diffusion](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~shuman/NEXT/MATERIALS%26COMPONENTS/Xe_damage/Crank-The-Mathematics-of-Diffusion.pdf)) and, at page 89, I could not understand the equation of radial diffusion:

$$\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial t}=D\bigg(\dfrac{\partial^2C}{\partial r^2}+\boxed{\dfrac{2}{r}\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial r}}\bigg).$$

What is the physical meaning of the boxed term?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diffusion equation is

$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}=D\Delta C\;.
$$

The boxed term arises from expressing the Laplacian $\Delta C$ of a radially symmetric function $C$ in spherical coordinates; you can derive it from the more symmetric expression $\frac1{r^2}\frac\partial{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial C}{\partial r}\right)$ by carrying out the outer differentiation. See Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Three_dimensions) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).

Comment: Thank you so much!